# Getting JSON Key Value from Firebase Datasnapshot

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

Meanwhile I am developing a Flutter app with Firebase and it is enjoyable indeed, of course there is hassle to overcome...

I setup a Firebase datastore, and through the firebase_database plugin I got a DataSnapshot returned as follow:

[image]

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users')
  .orderByChild('emailAddress')
  .equalTo('wonderjimmy@gmail.com').once()
  .then((onValue) {
   Map data = onValue.value;
  });
```

I use a Map object to keep this JSON. A stupid question: if I just want to get the value "**-L474-TYYYGPvCChlZCS**", how should I do?

Comment: There was een issue that firestore didn't expose the document id. It was kind of fixed by exposing the path. Not sure if you can work with that or if there is a better fix already. Reference: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/244

Comment: Why do you want to read the key itself when you can read all the values ?

Comment: Because I need to replace the values under the key. Actually getting the whole set is not a problem, I just want to know how to properly parse the returned result.

Comment: [You do not need to mark questions as "SOLVED" via editing the title](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/295637), or [posting updates/thanks in posts](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/109959/295637). Simply add your own answer, and mark as accepted if one of the answers here didn't give you a solution. Anything additional can be perceived as noise for future visitors. See: [Can I answer my own question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for accessing the key from DataSnapshot just use snapshot.key and you will have the relative key of the item in your case Users

```
 .then((onValue) {
   onValue.map(data => {
      var key = data.key
    })
 });
```

or just use as given in firebase docs inside then

```
.then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var key = childSnapshot.key; // you will get your key here
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I see. So how can I get the value "-L474-TYYYGPvCChlZCS" just under "users"?

Comment: after you get the snapshot inside the map you get snapshot right?

Comment: Yes, or any smarter approach ;)

Comment: are you getting the key like this i guess this is the way i know

Comment: Ok if it is users then try to map users and then try using key property

Comment: Seems the DataSnapshot returned is just a Map<String, dynamic>, no more no less. If onValue.key = "users", then the key of the first child is the value I want. Thanks Mahesh!

I will update the question with my finding.

Comment: This answer uses JavaScript syntax. Flutter uses Dart and the code should look different.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the key by snapshot.key, you can find a reference to it here:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  // ...
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if using snapshot.key the returned value would be "users".

Comment: Updated the response based on your query, there is a forEach method on the snapshot that iterates the childSnapshots with key and val() props

Comment: Thanks Alex, let me try that tonight.

BTW, what I want to do is getting the child key then set the updated JSON back to the original position, what is the best practice for doing something like this? Is iterating the snapshot inevitable?

Comment: When you request a snapshot of the db with a criteria it returns a list or null, you have to validate that it exists (not null), store it as you see fit for further use then iterate over the children & / or pick the first match

Comment: This answer uses JavaScript syntax. Flutter uses Dart and the code should look different.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.then(res => {
      // console.log(res)
      const data = res.data
      // extracting firebase ids for manipulating existing notes
      for (let key in data) {
        const item = data[key]
        item.id = key
        console.log(item.id)
      }
```