# Flutter: Parsing Firebase Realtime Database snapshot to list

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried searching other questions but the only similar question to this had answers in [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48536748/getting-json-key-value-from-firebase-datasnapshot/53884866) instead of Dart/Flutter. I'm trying to get a list from my Firebase Realtime Database into my app as a `List<BaseModel>`

So far from what I've searched in the net, I think the result of the `DataSnapshot` is a map that I could parse so I tried it out but got this error: `List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>`

My Code:

```dart
Future<List<BaseModel>> getList(
    {DatabaseReference query, Models modelType}) async {
  List<BaseModel> list = new List();
  DataSnapshot snap = await query.once();
  Map<String, dynamic> json = Map.from(snap.value);
  json.forEach((key, value) {
    list.add(BaseModel(model: modelType, key: key, snapshot: value));
  });
  return list;
}
```

The weird thing is, even if I try to parse a non-list model I also get the same error.

My database structure looks like this:

[image]

**Update:**

BaseModel:

```dart
abstract class BaseModel {
  factory BaseModel({Models model, String key, Map map}) {
    switch (model) {
      case Models.MyModel:
        return MyMod.fromSnapshot(key: key, map: map);
        break;
      default:
        throw ("Not a valid model.");
    }
  }
}
```

MyModel:

```dart
MyModel.fromSnapshot({String key, Map map}) {
  _id = key;
  _title = map['title'];
}
```

My Firebase query is just the database reference with `.child("Root")`

Comment: Can you please share your BaseModel and your Firebase query?

Comment: Ps. I could just add 100 because the items I am storing number less than that per node but if you have no ceiling on the key then you just need to code it so that it starts with a non-zero value, I guess.

Comment: Hi I added my BaseModel and query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution!

My new code:

```dart
Future<List<BaseModel>> getList({DatabaseReference query, Models modelType}) async {
  List<BaseModel> list = new List();
  DataSnapshot snap = await query.once();
  List<dynamic> resultList = snap.value;
  for(var i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = Map.from(resultList[i]);
    list.add(BaseModel(model: modelType, key: i.toString(), snapshot: map));
  }
  return list;
}
```

This should work assuming you parse the values from your model's `.fromMap(yourMap)` constructor method. Something like `_title = yourMap['key'];`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience where the snapshot.value sometimes returned a List and sometimes returned a Map. I searched for a long time to get an answer with no luck but I came up with a workaround.
I suspected that the problem was being caused by using a record key with a value of zero so I added 100 to each key before I wrote it to the db and then subtracted it when I had read and was processing the records. The problem went away in that I then always got a Map returned.
I have since seen a reason given for this behaviour and it confirmed that the zero key value was the culprit but unfortunately I didn't save the link. I think it was on one of the Firebase blogs.
I think the 0 record returns a List and the ones with positive values return a Map.
Anyway, try the adding 100 trick and see it that helps. if it helps, upvote me....I don't think you need code to add or delete 100. :-)

Found the article, Firebase is deciding if it should render an array or a map based on the snapshot content: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html?m=1

**UPDATE:**

My 'starting at 0' theory was a red herring, sorry.

The key to this behaviour (bits in **bold**) is in the part of the Firebase blog (link above) that states:

> However, to help people that are storing arrays in Firebase, when you
>   call .val() or use the REST api to read data, **if the data looks like
>   an array, Firebase will render it as an array.**
>
> **In particular, if all of the keys are integers, and more than half of
>   the keys between 0 and the maximum key in the object have non-empty
>   values, then Firebase will render it as an array.** This latter part is
>   important to keep in mind.
>
> // we send this ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] // Firebase stores this {0:
>   'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}
>
> // since the keys are numeric and sequential, // if we query the data,
>   we get this ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>
> // however, if we then delete a, b, and d, // they are no longer
>   mostly sequential, so // we do not get back an array {2: 'c', 4: 'e'}
>   You can't currently change or prevent this behavior.

I have now tested this by setting up a db node that looks like the below image. I tested what was being returned in `snapshot.value` by using `snapshot.value is List` and `snapshot.value is Map`, both return true or false.

When ONLY nodes 0, 1 and 3 were there, Firebase RTDB was happily returning a List in `snapshot.value`. When I added nodes 4 and 6, which have inconsistent data, it decided it was time to return a Map. :-)

So, the quick fix is to test the contents of snapshot.value with `is List` and/or `is Map` and then process the contents accordingly, otherwise rethink your keys...the fact that they are sequential or close-to-sequential (with gaps) but have the same children structure is the issue.

[image]

Comment: I dont think it has to do with the key being 0. I tried changing the database to use strings as its key but I still got the same error